# Hadoop Mutlicluster installation on Amazon ubuntu instances

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, hadoop, amazon-ec2

In all the explanations of installation of hadoop on linux, the mention of folders like : hadoop/etc or hadoop/bin occurs.
However, after I downloaded, extracted and renamed hadoop, my hadoop folder contains the following subfolders: 
!https://s13.postimg.org/kvhy23r47/capture32.png

So my hadoop folder does not contain the folders etc and bin

The other files that are referred to in the installation guides (which are expected to be present in hadoop/conf) such as core-sie.xml, hadoop-env.sh, yarn-site.xml and mapred-site.xml are all present in one subfolder or the other, and i have individually accessed the files to edit them.

But I am sure that I'm doing something wrong. 
Can anyone help me know where am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I understood my mistake

I was downloading src file from the release page of hadoop. I should download the binaries